# Cannot grab LeftMouseButtonGesture when called by a signal

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

I've list of items and I need to view detailed information of the item when clicked on it. Since the number of items and their details are huge, I need to be able scroll them with left mouse button (can't use scrollbars due to UI preferences).

[image: Left button scroll not works in here]

I can scroll both `QTableWidget` and `QTextEdit` when I called the `view_details` method explicitly.

The problem is; when I connect the `cellClicked` signal to the `view_details` scroll with left button is no longer works.

I suspected that the `QTableWidget` intercepts gesture events and created an event filter, but found out the event is not generated at all. I'm providing a minimal sample to reproduce the behavior:

```
# PySide 5.15.2.1

from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QTableWidget,
    QTextEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QScroller,
    QDialog,
)
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

DUMMYTEXT = """
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sagittis venenatis metus eget lobortis. Quisque purus neque, 
            faucibus ac molestie sit amet, mollis ut lectus. Cras interdum volutpat lacus dignissim rutrum. Curabitur non magna et justo 
            condimentum mattis. Sed nec congue mi. Duis lacinia enim sed enim consequat, facilisis sagittis nunc malesuada. Sed nec 
            commodo orci. In feugiat efficitur elit, vel finibus urna gravida in. Duis a nunc in dolor rhoncus egestas vel ac leo. Nullam 
            scelerisque facilisis lorem in sodales. Curabitur mattis, lacus commodo lobortis pulvinar, lorem neque malesuada massa, nec 
            elementum lectus metus lobortis ante. Nulla sed lorem lacus.
            
            Nullam pharetra finibus sem. Nulla diam enim, accumsan tempus lacinia a, mattis sed sapien. Suspendisse dapibus neque eget 
            purus pellentesque, vel porttitor lectus eleifend. Integer sed ante lacus. Pellentesque pretium maximus enim ut suscipit. 
            Curabitur eu urna elit. Nunc eget feugiat odio, non posuere mi. Nam lacinia tellus sed massa efficitur vestibulum. Maecenas 
            pharetra mattis lectus, et consequat magna finibus sit amet. Mauris non urna hendrerit, mattis eros et, rutrum sapien. 
            Praesent tortor nunc, fringilla ac neque quis, feugiat tristique libero. Pellentesque ultrices tristique augue vitae tristique.
            """


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(200, 300)
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(10)
        self.table_widget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        for i in range(10):
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText("Item")
            self.table_widget.setItem(i, 0, item)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setScroller(self.table_widget)

        ### Gesture is successfully grabbed by QDialog's QTextEdit when directly called
        self.view_details()

        ### Gesture is not grabbed by QDialog's QTextEdit when called by the signal of QTableWidget which also grabs the gesture
        self.table_widget.cellClicked.connect(self.view_details)

    def setScroller(self, widget):
        scroller = QScroller.scroller(widget)
        scroller.grabGesture(widget, QScroller.LeftMouseButtonGesture)

    def view_details(self):
        dialog = QDialog(self)

        text_edit = QTextEdit(dialog)
        text_edit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        text_edit.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        text_edit.setText(DUMMYTEXT)

        self.setScroller(text_edit)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(dialog)
        layout.addWidget(text_edit)

        dialog.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    main_widget = MyWidget()
    main_widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

In this example, scrolling with the left mouse button will work in the first shown dialog, but it won't work when you click a table cell. Is there any way to achieve this functionality in both cases?

Comment: It seems like there's some conflict with the mouse press used for both the scroller and the item selection. I'm able to reproduce the issue but if I don't release the mouse instantly, then it works as expected. There's also a small delay in the selection change when the scroller is set that doesn't exist if the scroller is not set on the view.

Comment: Yes, it is happens on all signals that rely on the left mouse button. It works as expected when `itemPressed` is connected and the right mouse button used. I'll probably have to change it to view details when double clicked or TapAndHold

Comment: As far as I can understand, the issue is caused by the QScroller gesture "grabbing" and delaying the mouse press event (the delayed selection when pressing is a clear symptom), which becomes inconsistent with the mouse press/move/release of item views. Fundamentally, it seems like the view "eats" the button release, preventing QScroller to properly manage the newly shown widget. Unfortunately I don't have enough time and focus right now to dig into it, but I believe it may be an important bug to report.